# Altering Setters and Getters Via User Input

Tags: java

I have tried a few things and I cannot seem to work this out. I'd like to keep a set price for the iPhone object that is defined by the latest user input.

Below is my Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Iphone iphone = new Iphone();

        iphone.setPrice();

        System.out.println(iphone.getPrice());

    }
}
```

Below is my Iphone class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Iphone {
    //Class Attributes
    private double price;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Constructer method
    public Iphone(){
        this.price = price;
    }

    //Getter Method
    public double getPrice() {
        return 0;
    }

    //Setter Method
    public void setPrice() {
        System.out.println("Enter a new price: ");
        String price = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The price has now been adjusted to " + price);
    }

    //toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Iphone{" +
                "price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then, when I typed 800 into the console, instead of showing 800, it'll show 0.0, example below of how it prints to the console:

Enter a new price:
800 //what i typed in
The price has now been adjusted to 800
0.0

Now... I know it is because I am returning 0 in the getter method, so what do I return instead to get the desired result, as it's obviously going to print 0.0 but when I type *return double userInput* for example, that doesn't work. Note: I am still in the beginner stage of learning Java. Thank you in advance for any help given to me.

Comment: I think you should go through a few Java tutorials.

Comment: Of course I disagree :-) You've been given some very specific advice, which solves your immediate problem, but doesn't explain that idiomatic Java setters are not what you have in your class. Try learning in a more structured way rather than in snippets from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set class variable to input variable as `this.price = Double.parseDouble(price)`

```
public void setPrice() {
        System.out.println("Enter a new price: ");
        String price = userInput.nextLine();
        this.price = Double.parseDouble(price);
        System.out.println("The price has now been adjusted to " + price);
}
```

Comment: I changed the return value in the getter method to price. And also, implemented what you said... AND IT WORKED! THANK YOU. I'm honestly so thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Your getPrice() method should return price field. And in setPrice() method you need to assign field price.